# Invertibility, diagonalization, trace and dimensions test exercise

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, trace

> Let $V$ be a vector space, $\dim(V)=5$.
>
> Let be $T:v \rightarrow V$ a linear operator that verifies:
>
> - $T$ is not invertible
> - $\dim(\operatorname{Ker}(T+4I))=2$
> - $\dim(\operatorname{Im}(T-I))=3$
>
> The associated matrix of $T$ in any basis of $V$ is denoted $A$.
>
> **Check the correct option:**
>
> **A)** $A$ is diagonalizable and $\operatorname{tr}(A)=-3$
>
> **B)** $A$ is diagonalizable and $\operatorname{tr}(A)=-6$
>
> **C)** $A$ is diagonalizable and $\operatorname{tr}(A)=-5$
>
> **D)** $A$ is not diagonalizable and $\operatorname{tr}(A)=0$

Well, I don't really know where to begin. I suspect the solution has to do with a lot of properties and so on but I'm not seeing it. Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The given information is sufficient for finding the dimensions of all (three) eigenspaces of $T$. Note that $v \in \ker(T+4I)$ just means $Tv = -4Iv = -4v$, so $\ker(T+4I)$ is the eigenspace of $T$ belonging to the eigenvalue $-4$. Since its dimension is $2$ we can find two linearly independent eigenvectors $v_1,v_2$ for the eigenvalue $-4$.

Of course we also have that $\ker(T-I)$ is the eigenspace of $T$ belonging to the eigenvalue $1$, and by rank-kernel-theorem
$$
\dim(\ker(T-I)) = \dim(V)-\dim(Im(T-I))= 5-3 = 2.
$$
Then we can also find two linearly independent eigenvectors $v_3,v_4$ belonging to eigenvalue $1$.

Finally, $T$ is not invertible, implying the existence of $0 \ne v_5 \in V$ s.t. $Tv_5=0$. Which is simply an eigenvector with corresponding eigenvalue $0$.

Then $(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4,v_5)$ form a basis of $V$ and the associated matrix of $T$ with respect to this basis is $diag(-4,-4,1,1,0)$.

So $A$ is diagonalisable, and trace is invariant under change of basis, so $trc(A)=-4-4+1+1=-6$.